# I'm tyring to turn VBB3 Plugin to VBB4

Tags: php

I really like this code https://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=90869
ANd I'm trying to turn it into VBB4.

Here is my what I have so far. I tried to fix it

**bbcode_parse_start**

```
foreach ($this->tag_list['option'] AS $tag => $bbcode)
{
    if (strpos($bbcode['html'], '{option1}'))
    {
       $this->tag_list['option']["$tag"]['replace'] = preg_replace('/\{option(\d+)\}',
        create_function ('$option',"'%' . (intval('\\1')+1) . '\$s'" , $bbcode['html'])
        unset($this->tag_list['option']["$tag"]['html']);
        $this->tag_list['option']["$tag"]['callback'] = 'handle_external';
        $this->tag_list['option']["$tag"]['external_callback'] = 'handle_bbcode_multioption';
    }
}
```

**bbcode_fetch_tags**

```
if (!function_exists('handle_bbcode_multioption'))
{
    function handle_bbcode_multioption(&$parser, $param, $options)
    {
        $taginfo = $parser->tag_list['option'][$parser->current_tag['name']];
        $replace = array($param);
            $replace = array_merge($param, explode('|', $options));
            return @vsprintf($taginfo['replace'], $replace);
    }

}
```

Comment: And what's your question? Or problem? Or whatever you're here for?

Comment: Oh sorry. I want to ask if you guys can help me fix it and make it work on VBB4

Comment: If you have tried to do something and it didn't work, then ask a question about the specific problem you are struggling with. If you want us to rewrite code for you, then no, hire a consultant.